# How to differentiate between a page reload and page rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Is there any way to identify when the page reloads using react functional component. I am aware of how we can use `constructor` in React Class components to know when the page reload occurs, but is it possible to identify the same using a function component?

This code will print "page rerender" every time the page rerenders

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("page rerender")
})
```

How to achieve the same for page reload?

Comment: Why do you want this? React views are a function of state. Why do you care whether you got to a particular state by state update or by reload?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev because i hav a component in my project which i want to show only when the page reloads or the router path changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The React Class component's `constructor` is the wrong place to track when a component mounts, e.g. loads. React Class components have the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods. The synonymous React function component version is the `useEffect` hook and its dependency array.

You can differentiate between a "mounting" effect and a regular effect based on how the hook's dependency array is used.

- The `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array will run once at the end of the initial render cycle.
- The `useEffect` hook with no dependency array will run once as the end of each render cycle, including the initial render cycle.

Use both to track/log both conditions.

```js
// Sort of like componentDidMount
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Page mounted");
}, []); // <-- run once

// Sort of like componentDidMount + componentDidUpdate
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Page rendered");
}); // <-- run each render cycle
```

> What I was trying to achieve is to call a function in my project if
> the route of the page changes or if the page reloads for that
> initially

Use the `useLocation` hook exported from React-Router and use `location.pathname` as the dependency in a `useEffect` hook.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { pathname } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  // Run effect on initial render cycle and
  // when the route path changes
}, [pathname]);
```

Comment: what i was trying to achieve is to call a function in  my project if the route of the page chagnes or if the page reloads for that initially i tried using  useEffect hook with an empty dependency array put it only worked when the page gets reloaded and not when the path is changed

Comment: @reedrichards What routing library are you using? It should be pretty trivial to listen for route changes.

Comment: i am using  react-router-dom

Comment: @reedrichards Use the `useLocation` hook and route location in the `useEffect` dependency array. I've updated my answer with example.